# iOS - how do I specify the index path of every UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, nsindexpath

I'm trying to use a CollectionView as a nice layout for my navigation buttons. I have a big If....else statement but I'm getting the error:

> Semantic Issue Property 'indexPath' not found on object of type 'UICollectionViewCell *'

Here is the code that is giving the error. There must be a better way to get the index paths for the cell.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if (_navCell.indexPath = @"0 - 0")
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toPersonnel" sender:self];
}
else if (_navCell.indexPath = @"0 - 1")
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toEquipment" sender:self];
}
else if (_navCell.indexPath = @"0 - 2")
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toTasks" sender:self];
}
else if (_navCell.indexPath = @"0 - 3")
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toTriage" sender:self];
}
else if (_navCell.indexPath = @"0 - 4")
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toLogs" sender:self];
}
else if (_navCell.indexPath = @"0 - 5")
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toMapping" sender:self];
}
else if (_navCell.indexPath = @"0 - 6")
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toHeadsUp" sender:self];
}
else if (_navCell.indexPath = @"0 - 7")
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toMessenger" sender:self];
}
}
```

And the other code for my collection view:

```
@interface mainViewController ()
  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionViewCell *navCell;
@end
```

the viewdidload:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
navItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[navItems addObject:@"personnel"];
[navItems addObject:@"equipment"];
[navItems addObject:@"tasks"];
[navItems addObject:@"triage"];
[navItems addObject:@"logs"];
[navItems addObject:@"mapping"];
[navItems addObject:@"headsup"];
[navItems addObject:@"messenger"];
}
```

Collection view methods

```
-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [navItems count];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
UIImageView *image = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[navItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

return cell;
}
```

Could someone show the proper way to find the indexPath of the different cells so I can connect them to my segues?

Thanks

Comment: Did you notice that `indexPath` is a *parameter* of that method?

Comment: Why only one "=" in your `if`? If you only have one section, do if `if([indexPath row] == x)` instead, where `x`is an `int`.

Comment: I understand my method is wrong. please don't down vote. If it was not wrong I would not need to ask on here the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many things wrong with your `didSelectRow...` method.

1. The method has an `indexPath` parameter
2. Your check to compare the index path is all wrong
3. Use an array

Try this:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *segue = segues[indexPath.row];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:segue sender:self];
}
```

Add an instance variable for `segues` as `NSArray *segues;`.

Then in `viewDidLoad` you can initialize it:

```
segues = @[ @"toPersonnel", @"toEquipment", @"toTasks" /* and the rest */ ];
```

Comment: Yes this method works perfectly. Thank you. I just misunderstood answers from similar questions.